# How to use Elmo word embedding with the original pre-trained model (5.5B) in interactive mode

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, allennlp

I am trying to learn how to use Elmo embeddings via this tutorial:

https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/tutorials/how_to/elmo.md

I am specifically trying to use the interactive mode as described like this:

```
$ ipython
> from allennlp.commands.elmo import ElmoEmbedder
> elmo = ElmoEmbedder()
> tokens = ["I", "ate", "an", "apple", "for", "breakfast"]
> vectors = elmo.embed_sentence(tokens)

> assert(len(vectors) == 3) # one for each layer in the ELMo output
> assert(len(vectors[0]) == len(tokens)) # the vector elements 
correspond with the input tokens

> import scipy
> vectors2 = elmo.embed_sentence(["I", "ate", "a", "carrot", "for", 
"breakfast"])
> scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vectors[2][3], vectors2[2][3]) # cosine 
distance between "apple" and "carrot" in the last layer
0.18020617961883545
```

My overall question is how do I make sure to use the pre-trained elmo model on the original 5.5B set (described here: https://allennlp.org/elmo)?

I don't quite understand why we have to call "assert" or why we use the [2][3] indexing on the vector output.

My ultimate purpose is to average the all the word embeddings in order to get a sentence embedding, so I want to make sure I do it right!

Thanks for your patience as I am pretty new in all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ElmoEmbedder` uses the Original weights and options from the pretrained models on the 1 Bil Word benchmark. About 800 million tokens. To ensure you're using the largest model, look at the arguments of the `ElmoEmbedder` class. From here you could probably figure out that you can set the options and weights of the model:

```
elmo = ElmoEmbedder(
    options_file='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/elmo/2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_5.5B/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_5.5B_options.json', 
    weight_file='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/elmo/2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_5.5B/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_5.5B_weights.hdf5'
)
```

I got these links from the pretrained models table provided by AllenNLP.

---

`assert` is a convenient way to test and ensure specific values of variables. This looks like [a good resource](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) to read more. For example, the first `assert` statement ensure the embedding has three output matrices.

---

Going off of that, we index with `[i][j]` because the model outputs 3 layer matrices (where we choose the i-th) and each matrix has `n` tokens (where we choose the j-th) each of length 1024. Notice how the code compares the similarity of "apple" and "carrot", both of which are the 4th token at index j=3. From the example documentation, i represents one of:

> The first layer corresponds to the context insensitive token
>   representation, followed by the two LSTM layers. See the ELMo paper or
>   follow up work at EMNLP 2018 for a description of what types of
>   information is captured in each layer.

The paper provides the details on those two LSTM layers.

---

Lastly, if you have a set of sentences, with ELMO you don't need to average the token vectors. The model is a character-wise LSTM, which works perfectly fine on tokenized whole sentences. Use one of the methods designed for working with sets of sentences: `embed_sentences()`, `embed_batch()`, etc. [More in the code](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/commands/elmo.py)!

Comment: Does embed_sentences() do straight forward vector averaging?